# How to globally override default Colors.blue color for the ThemeData?

Tags: flutter

In flutter even when I set

```
primaryColor: Colors.orange,
```

then in some part of the UI the default Colors.blue is still present.
Is there a way how to globally override it for the ThemeData?

Comment: Parts of the UI by default like overscrolling uses the accentColor property which is by default Colors.blue too

Comment: @ShaanFaydh now the accentColor property is deprecated so there is an issue

Comment: Well just replace it with `colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.orange),`

Comment: @ShaanFaydh `'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart': Failed assertion: line 350 pos 12: 'colorScheme?.brightness == null || brightness == null || colorScheme!.brightness == brightness': is not true.` when using it.

Answer (score 5):

In order for me to override Colors.blue, I had to state primarySwatch in the ThemeData and also the colorScheme, as in

```
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.orange),
),
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

primarySwatch: Colors.orange